# Getting value from dropdown on master page

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have a **master page** and a Default.aspx page. My drop down `<select>` is on the Master Page.

I want to select a month from the drop down on the master page and assign it to a variable in a different class. Then, the default.aspx page must use that variable to select data from database where the date is equals to the date I assigned to the variable.

The reason why the select on the master page, is because the selector should be on **ALL** the pages through out the site.

The main thing that is causing this issue for me is the `Page_Load event` on the defauls.aspx page that fires **BEFORE** the Page_Load in the Master page.

If I try `Page_Init`, it works, but the selector code keeps returning 0 as the value. I also tried using a `HiddenField` and it also failed. I appreciate ANY help on this!

---

**Site1.Master:**

```
               <select id="SelectMonth" runat="server" onchange="CmbChange();">
                    <option id="Select" value="0">[Select Month]</option>
                    <option id="January" value="1">January</option>
                    <option id="February" value="2">February</option>
                    <option id="March" value="3">March</option>
                    <option id="April" value="4">April</option>
                    <option id="May" value="5">May</option>
                    <option id="June" value="6">June</option>
                    <option id="July" value="7">July</option>
                    <option id="August" value="8">August</option>
                    <option id="September" value="9">September</option>
                    <option id="October" value="10">October</option>
                    <option id="November" value="11">November</option>
                    <option id="December" value="12">December</option>
                </select>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function CmbChange(obj) {
                        var cmbValue = document.getElementById("SelectMonth").value;
                        __doPostBack('SelectMonth', cmbValue);
                    }
                </script>
```

**Site1.Master.cs:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(SelectMonth.Value);

        if (month > 0)
        {
            Date.Month = month;
        }
        else
        {
            Date.Month = DateTime.Now.Month;
        } 
    }
```

**Default.aspx:**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Example
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Month = " + Date.Month;
    }
```

**Date.cs:**

```
public static class Date
{
    public static int Month { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the relevant code in your question instead of providing a link, it will help you in getting an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try using the Default.aspx.vb `Page_PreRender`, and use the `Page_Load` on the MasterPage to get the value then?

Or alternatively use an include:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/Site.Master"  %>
```

And call a function wrote in your MasterPage to get the DropDown value using:

```
Master.FunctionNamedOnMasterPage()
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx) is a link to the MSDN site on how to reference MasterPage content

Comment: Thanks! I used Page_PreRender on default.aspx and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume the `Load` of the control and set the variable there because the controls are loaded before the page is.